# SP.Taxonomy.js TypeError: b.get_path is not a function

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, taxonomy

I'm trying to display the terms of a site but I can't create a instance of TermSession object.

```
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
```

This code displays the following error (firebug):

> TypeError: b.get_path is not a function
>   SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession()

I've tried in two different SharePoint 2013 environments (online and in premise)

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you load sp.taxonomy.js script file from _layouts/15 ?

Comment: Yes, I did. The error is inside the getTaxonomySession method

Answer (score 2):

I think I found my mistake... 
It's seems that sp.runtime.js has to be loaded manually.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.taxonomy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){       
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.Runtime.js', 'SP.Runtime', function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.Taxonomy.js', 'SP.Taxonomy', loadTerms)
        });
    });
});
```

And then I could load my terms normally.

```
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var session = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
context.load(session);
var termStore = session.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
context.load(session);
context.load(termStore);
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        var termStoresEnum = termStore.getEnumerator();
```

Thanks for the advice.